# Create Google Map v3 After Clicking On An Element

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dynamic, onclick

What I would like to do is create a map after an element is clicked on.  I'm using Google Maps v3.

I have a Realty listing page that shows 15 results/properties per page.  Instead of generating 15 maps I would like 1 map to be created when I click on an element.  Once clicked on, the map generation process takes place.  The map canvas/div is initially hidden.

I was thinking that the click element and map element relationship would be something like this:

```
<span id="12-1234" lat="10.101010" lng="-25.252525" class="view-map">View Map</span>
... other markup ...
<div id="12-1234-map" class="google-map"></div>
```

Using HTML5 I add custom attributes to the element about the property like *id*, *latitude* and *longitude* so I can change the icon and center the map.

I've got a functioning map from which I load markers from a dynamically generated XML file based on the search parameters.

I've been looking at addListener and addDomListener but haven't had any luck.  Most searches just pull up issues related to markers.

I had a wonky thing that sort of worked that used jQuery.  Something like this:

```
$('.view-map').click(function(){
     google.maps.event.addDomListener( this, 'click', initialize );
     $("#" + this.id + "-map").toggle();
});
```

Obviously this wasn't perfect as you'd have to click the element a couple more times before seeing the map as you've bound another click event to it after having already clicking on it.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function initialize(link) {
  var mapDiv = $('#' + link.attr('id') + '-map');
  mapDiv.toggle();

  var options = {
    zoom: 10,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(link.attr('lat'), link.attr('lng'))
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv[0], options);
}

$('.view-map').click(function(){
  initialize(this);
});
```

Comment: I am getting closer.  This creates the map on the correct DIV.  But now I get an error, _map not defined_.  This is in reference to my _createMarker()_ function.

`function createMarker( latlng, address ) {
 
 var html = '<div>some HTML stuff</div>';

 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({ content: html }); 
 
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlng,
      map: map,
      title: address
     });
 
  google.maps.event.addListener( marker, 'click', function() {
  infoWindow.open( map, marker );
 }); 

 return marker;
}`

Comment: I have rectified my error.  I was defining `var map;` after my _createrMarker()_ function yet before my _initialize()_ funciton.  Not quite sure why that was an issue.  If you could, please explain why _mapDiv[0]_ works vs _mapDiv_.

Comment: I had done something just like this, just no jQuery within the _initialize()_ function.  As `var mapDiv = document.getElementById( link.id + '-map' );` also works and no need for _mapDiv[0]_.  I see now that you're only using _mapDiv[0]_ as it's a jQuery object and you need the elements object, i.e. [object HTMLDivElement].  Must have done something in the wrong order or some other small thing.  Thanks for the solution skarE!

Answer (score 0):

In your view-map click function, just call a map initialize method, passing in the appropriate values.  This initialize function can then show the map div, and then initialize the map appropriately.

Ugly and unchecked example:

```
var params = {
  lat : 47.5,
  lng : -122.5 }

$('.view-map').click(params, function(){
  params.id = this.id //e.g. 1234
  initialize(params);
  });

function initialize(params){
 // show the 1234-map div, initialize the map
}
```

Comment: I have tried something similar to this.  I will work off your example and see what I come up with.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yep, I had done something like this before.  The bridge I'm trying to gap is not passing parameters to the initialize() function.  Its telling the API to draw the map.  The Google Maps API articles use:
`google.maps.event.addDomListener( window, 'load', init )`

How can I do something similar within my initialize() function that will attach to the appropriate div?